# Do i need to lube up my chain

Tags: maintenance, chain

I didnt ride my bicycle for almost 2 years now. It was in my room all this time. Do i need to lube the chain up or am i good to go? Thanks! Benjamin.

Comment: After 2 years, you have to pump up the tires up, check the brakes and shifter cables etc a moving as they should, check shifting etc - spend the  30 seconds to add a squirt of lube to the chain.

Comment: At least wipe the dust off.  And a few squirts of lube from a squirt bottle (don't use sprays like WD-40!) won't hurt.  (After lubing, wipe the chain again.)

Answer (score 1):

Probably.  Is it oily?  If not lube it.

Answer (score 1):

I would clean it. If it was put away with lube on it, it is probably filthy. If it was put away dry, it needs lube.

Comment: Unless Dry lube was used....

Comment: Good point. But even with dry lube, if it has been sitting for 2 years, couldn't hurt to clean it and lube it. It never hurts to clean a chain.